# Fragment Transactions with transition - Unique transitionNames are required

Tags: android, transactions, fragment, transition, android-transitions

I want to go from a list view to the detail view and therefore, I use following `OnClickListener` in my list:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Bet bet = (Bet)view.getTag();
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    BetDetailFragment f = BetDetailFragment.create(bet);
    String tag = f.getClass().getName();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
        f.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move));
    }

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, f, tag)
            .addToBackStack(tag);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        L.d(this, "TRANS: " + TransitionUtil.getTransitionNameBetLogo1(bet) + "|" + view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo1));
        L.d(this, "TRANS: " + TransitionUtil.getTransitionNameBetLogo2(bet) + "|" + view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo2));
        ft.addSharedElement(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo1), "1");//TransitionUtil.getTransitionNameBetLogo1(bet));
        ft.addSharedElement(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo2), "2");//TransitionUtil.getTransitionNameBetLogo2(bet));
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

My functions return unique names, I have two different views, but still it does not work.
I already commented unnecessary functions out and wrote some unique transaction names in there by hand... But still, I get this exception, in the line of the first `addSharedElement`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unique transitionNames are required for all sharedElements
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.addSharedElement
```

**EDIT**

Without the shared elements, everything is working perfectly fine...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem is, that `addSharedElement` does NOT set the transaction name of the view!

So in my example I would have to set it with following code:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo1), "1");
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo2), "2");
```

BEFORE I add this views to the `FragmentTransaction`...

Afterwards following works just fine and as expected:

```
ft.addSharedElement(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo1), "1");
ft.addSharedElement(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo2), "2");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Don't need to assign a `transitionName` exactly equal to *SharedElement's name*. It's enough to view has only a `transitionName`. Actually ***SharedElement's name* MUST be equal to `transitionName` of *shared element* in the destination fragment**. See [here](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#96ab). Although these two `transitionName`s may be required to be equal (for some other reasons) but is not a requirement to prevent of *Unique transitionNames are required* error.

Answer (score 6):

You must set the same transitionName in the xml layout element of each fragment. For example:

Fragment A:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
 ...
 android:transitionName="transtion_name_example"/>
```

Fragment B:

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
 ...
 android:transitionName="transtion_name_example"/>
```

And the code will be something like this:

```
yourTransaction.addSharedElement(view, view.transactionName)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to only set a `transitionName` to your *shared element*. **There is no need for choosing it exactly equal to the name of your *shared element*** (that has been passed as the second argument of `addSharedElement()` method).

**This name (second parameter of `addSharedElement()`) MUST be equal to `transitionName` of the *shared element* in the *destination fragment*. See [here](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb#96ab).**

---

So *it's enough to insert*:

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo1), "AnyThing");
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view.findViewById(R.id.ivLogo2), "EveryThing");
```

before invoking `addSharedElement(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

before onClick

use this code

```
ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.ivImage, "value");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `onClickListener` is part of your fragment, not parent `Activity`, then you are doing things wrong here. Your fragment should notify parent activity what it wants and Activty should deal with it (i.e. by replacing fragments etc). Fragment should never do this by itself. Also if all you need is to go from detail view to list, then I assume you entered your detail view from that list. If so, all you need is to pop last element (fragment view fragment) fromt back stack. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Comment: just to clarify, the only problem is the animation of the shared elements... Changing fragments and so is working fine. To the other point, you're right, should be done in the activity... I was just to lazy to put the function there, as my fragment flows are really easy...